# Dual Boot Kali Linux With Optane Memory Installed

Tags: kali-linux

I have a gaming pc with an optane memory, 1TB HDD(GPT) and i am trying to install linux os on a separate partition i created on windows. Whilst installing the partitions are not displayed. What can i do?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know what to try. Never encountered a problem like this before.

Comment: You have presumably done some research, that's something, but you haven't told us anything about that so we can only assume you haven't.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the best answer. Just follow the steps in the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asapB9JnmEw

or...

Install optane memory and disable the optane drive then make a shrink in your hdd to install the other os later. after installation open windows and enable optane drive.

Comment: It doesn't matter that this is your own question that you have answered: answers on Superuser must be entirely contained within the post here and should not require watching or visiting any external content. External links can be used for attribution or additional research, but they should not be required for the answer.

Comment: i edited it. so dont downvote please